# Socket SSL morrendo no cliente e sem erros no servidor

Tags: python, smtp, socket, ssl

Estou com um problema em conexões com Sockets ssl em python

Quando realizo um teste de stress no daemon SMTP que estou escrevendo o client algumas threads de envio morrem com "***Connection reset by peer***" , porem do lado do servidor não há nenhuma exception e não realizo nenhum tratamento sobre o socket que possa estar capturando o erro.

O daemon é derivado da classe nativa do python SMTPServer e por consequência usa o asyncore.dispatcher para gerenciar as múltiplas conexões

Erro no client:

```
Exception in thread Thread-21:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "pop_bomb_client.py", line 45, in concurrent_thread
    sendmess(k)
  File "pop_bomb_client.py", line 31, in sendmess
    sempop=smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server,465)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 781, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 787, in _get_socket
    new_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(new_socket, self.keyfile, self.certfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 451, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 369, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

SocketSSL no Server:

```
def create_socket(self, family, stype):
    self.family_and_type = family, stype
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(family, stype),'cert.key', 'cert.cert',server_side=True, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    sock.setblocking(0)
    self.set_socket(sock)
```

Comment: Você já verificou seus certificados? Eles estão expirados ou são auto-assinados? Se sim, já viu se o cliente não está rejeitando a conexão por isso e você precisa habiltiar algo para forçar que ele aceite?

Comment: sim, é um certificado válido e esta ok, fiz testes com um fake e o unico porem do era aceitar o certificado no thunderbird, depois de aceitar uma vez ja passava a funcionar sem problema nenhum... o erro que tenho é só diante de carga... acho que na pratica  é o meu bot client que não esta performando... o server nem sente com 20 conexões simultâneas..

Comment: Coloque o codigo de como está executando as threads. Existem problemas relacionados a carga. Que tipo de servidor está usando para executar o server?

Comment: Seria interessante termos acesso ao código do seu client

Answer (score 4):

Ok,

Vamos la por que esse é um problema complexo com variáveis complexas também.

Seus detalhes foram poucos mas permitem inferir que:

1. estas usando o SSL do python;
2. Provavelmente estas trabalhando num servidor Linux ou conectando num;

O erro:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 369, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Refere-se basicamente a RECUSA de conexão do servidor para com o cliente.
Como temos poucos detalhes isso pode ser por basicamente:

1. Recusa do servidor em atender (devido a demanda);
2. Incapacidade de realizar o HandShake do SSL.

No seu codigo de server usaste o sock.setblocking(0) claramente deixando claro que não queres bloquear as conexões a documentação é clara:

```
In non-blocking mode, if a recv() call doesn’t find any data, or if a send() call can’t immediately dispose of the data, a error exception is raised;
```

Mas novamente como Não temos o codigo usado não sabemos como vc esta tratando essas exceções.

Outra suposição é que o openssl ta com o bug  numero 683159 criando esses erros de handshake, principalmente ocorre isso com servers apache.
A solução disso seria especificar no seu socket a versão 3 como por exemplo

```
 def create_socket(self, family, stype):
    self.family_and_type = family, stype
    sock = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(family, stype),'cert.key', 'cert.cert',server_side=True,ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3)
```

Espero ter resolvido esse problema e tenha uma boa semana